# Are there (detailed) images or diagrams of the rotating drill carousel and the small robotic arm which are housed in the belly of Perseverance?

Tags: mars, sample-return, perseverance

The [sample handling page](https://mars.nasa.gov/mars2020/spacecraft/rover/sample-handling/) at the Mars 2020 mission site shows us the rover with at its front a circle that probably contains the rotating drill carousel ?
However it states that the **belly** of the rover houses that carousel and the 43 sample tubes and a small robotic arm for moving those tubes.

Is indeed the carousel within that circle at the front ( what I rather would name the **chest** than the **belly** ) ?

And are there other, more detailed images or diagrams of the carousel, the housing of the tubes, and the **small** robotic arm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This video, I think, answers your questions. I've taken a couple of screen grabs but the video really shows it. The relevant part starts about 1:30.

That UFO-shaped thing on the top front is the bit carousel and where the samples go in. It rotates until the sample tube is vertical.

[image]

Then the sample handling arm inside, grabs the sample tube out of the bit and moves it to the storage area in the belly.

[image]

Here's a picture of the sample storage area being installed in the belly.

[image]

(image [source](https://www.digitaltrends.com/news/nasa-perseverance-rover-sample-collection/))

Comment: Thank you, this answers the question completely ! I'm still confused though at what point the core sample will be placed into the sample tube  "Essentially, after our rotary percussive drill  takes a core sample,... https://mars.nasa.gov/news/8682/the-extraordinary-sample-gathering-system-of-nasas-perseverance-mars-rover/

Comment: @Cornelisinspace "During each sample collection, the core sample will go directly into the tube attached to the drill. That bit and the sample tube are brought back by the robotic arm — our first robot — into the second robot, our bit carousel, which receives the … filled sample tube." https://spaceflightnow.com/2020/06/16/with-super-clean-sample-tubes-installed-nasas-next-mars-rover-nearly-buttoned-up-for-launch/ Sounds like the bit contains the sample tube during drilling ops, then it gets removed and stored.

Comment: That  makes it clear !  So the bit with the core sample inside will go directly into the sample tube attached to the drill. Then with every new drilling a new bit and a new tube will have to be moved via the carousel to the turret of the robotic arm.

Comment: @Cornelisinspace I'm not clear on the 'new bit' part. It seems that there are more sample tubes than bits.  It's an interesting mechanism.

Comment: You're right, I was wrong about the "new bit" part. "For core sampling, a sample tube is inserted *inside* the appropriate bit (*on the carousel*) before the carousel moves  the combination into position for the drill. "  ( to extract it.)  "Once the sample tube has been filled, the robotic arm returns the drill bit and tube (still inside) to the carousel where  they wend their way.... (I think the drill bit will stay in the carousel), https://phys.org/news/2019-08-robotic-toolkit-added-nasa-mars.html